# Generate array of longest matches between an string and an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is hard for me to explain the logic but I think if you give it a try it shouldn't be that hard. I'll try my best to describe this. any comments or solution are greatly appreciated.

We have a single reference sentence:

```
const referenceSentence = "your majesty they are ready";
```

And we have an array of compare sentences (for now let say it has a single sentence):

```
const compareSentences  = [
   "your highness they are ready",
];
```

We want to generate a `result` array with this features:

- if you join the elements of this array it gives you `referenceSentence`. actually this array is just `referenceSentence` which is separated to array of phrases or parts.
- elements or phrases in this array separated based on longest possible match in `compareSentences` and also phrases or parts that don't match.

For Instance in above `referenceSentence` and  `compareSentences` we have these longest matches:

"**your**" and "**they are ready**" so these two should be included in the `result` array.

And also "**majesty**" which don't match and it should be included too... because as I said if you join elements of `result` we should get `referenceSentence`.

So the `result` would be :

```
result = ["your", "majesty", "they are ready"]
```

Note that we separated the `referenceSentence` into array of phrases based on longest possible matches...

What I mean by longest possible matches?

I mean although "they" and  "are" and "ready" matches in both but **we shouldn't get this result**:

```
result = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"]
```

Again note that the result array is just the `referenceSentence` separated to phrases based on `compareSentences` longest matches.

And if we have this one as the `compareSentences` array:

```
const compareSentences = [
       "your highness they are ready",
       "your highness they are coming",
];
```

This time we can not have "**they are ready**" as one of the phrases of our desired `result`, because the second element in the `compareSentences` array only give us a share of "**they are**" with the `referenceSentence` so the desired result this time should be:

```
 result = ["your", "majesty", "they are", "ready"]
```

And if we have this one as the `compareSentences` array:

```
const compareSentences= [
     "your highness they are ready",
     "your highness they are coming",
     "and finally we are coming",
];
```

The result should be:

```
result = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"]
```

So far I can check the shared parts of the sentence a with b: (you may not find this useful to solve this problem)

```js
function exactMatch(a, b) {
  a = a.split(' ');
  b = b.split(' ');
  let s = [];
  let out = [];
  let x = a.map(x => b.includes(x) ? x : null);
  x.forEach((v) => {
    if (v == null) {    
    out.push(s);
      s = [];
    } else {
      s.push(v);
    }
  });
  out.push(s);
  out = out.map(x => x.join(' ')).filter(x => x);
  return out;
}
let a = "your majesty they are ready";
let b = "your highness they are ready";
let c = exactMatch(a, b);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: You already [asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230120/generate-an-array-of-phrases-for-the-reference-base-on-the-longest-possible-buil). You should edit that question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: How much does the order of the words matter?  For instance, how does that compare with `"my queen they know your majesty is coming"`?  "your majesty" is in both, but in different positions.  What if a common phrase is repeated in either the target or one of the comparisons?

Comment: the `result` is just the `referenceSentence` which is separated to phrases so there is no ordering issue at all. we want to turn `referenceSentence` into array of phrases so in your example considering the sentence you provided is the only compare sentence, we should get this array as the `result`: `["your majesty", "they ", "are ready"]`

Comment: Why is there a trailing space only on `"your "` in your expected output?  If you need the space, then I would expect it to be on all but the final value.  But it would seem cleaner without the space, to be followed by a `.join (' ')`

Comment: that is a mistake... We don't care to trailing spaces...

Comment: I have edited that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion will make this easier.

This solution uses two recursive functions.  `longestInitialMatch` is a helper function that finds the longest initial set of words that is included in all the comparison strings.  It does this by checking if either the target string is a substring of all the comparisons or the target string is a single word.  If either is true, it returns the target string.  Otherwise it recurs on the target string less its last word.

`breakdown`, the main function, starts by calling `longestInitialMatch` to get the initial entry.  If that is equivalent to the whole target, then we return an array containing just that.  If not, we return an array starting with that value, followed by all the results of a recursive call on the remaining words.

```js
const longestInitialMatch = (ref, cmps) =>
  cmps .every (cmp => cmp .includes (ref)) || ! ref .includes (' ')
    ? ref
    : longestInitialMatch (ref .slice (0, ref .lastIndexOf (' ')), cmps) 

const breakdown = (ref, cmps, init = longestInitialMatch (ref, cmps)) => 
  init === ref
    ? [init]
    : [init, ... breakdown (ref .slice (init .length + 1), cmps)]

console .log (breakdown ("your majesty they are ready", [
  "your highness they are ready",
]))

console .log (breakdown ("your majesty they are ready", [
  "your highness they are ready",
  "your highness they are coming",
]))

console .log (breakdown ("your majesty they are ready", [
  "your highness they are ready",
  "your highness they are coming",
  "and finally we are coming",
]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I prefer the above ES6 syntax.  But you can do the same with older JS, with something like this:

```js
function longestInitialMatch (ref, cmps) {
  return cmps .every (cmp => cmp .includes (ref)) || ! ref .includes (' ')
    ? ref
    : longestInitialMatch (ref .slice (0, ref .lastIndexOf (' ')), cmps)
}

function breakdown (ref, cmps) {
  const init = longestInitialMatch (ref, cmps) 
  return init === ref
    ? [init]
    : [init] .concat (breakdown (ref .slice (init .length + 1), cmps))
}
```

Comment: For the first tests it was amazing... WOW... you've done something in less than 10 line which I can't do it in 1000 lines... Thanks a lot Scott... plus one for now.. please let me test this more and I'll com back to you...

Comment: This one was more about figuring out an appropriate algorithm than about how to implement it.  There are many conceivable implementations of the basic idea.  Recursion simply gives us a good way to do so elegantly.